# Run brute force on a column to identify if the values cross over a point using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am wondering how I can write a VBA code to check if my data crosses over a certain point of interest. I have a column of approx. 40,000 data points that linearly increase and decrease (i.e 0 to 10 and then back down from 10 to 0). I want to identify when the points cross over a value and perform interpolation on corresponding data values. For example, I would like to write a code that will pick every time my data set crosses 4.1, and perform interpolation on the corresponding cell values in another column.

This is what I have tried so far

```
    'Calculate how many data points are present in worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Identify the data colum as pot1 throughout code
Set pot1 = Range("N14:N" & lastRow)

Dim i As Integer
'data starts from line 14 of worksheet
For i = 14 To lastRow

'check to see if the cell above contains text, if it does, line a tells it to skip that cell and move to next one
If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Cells(i - 1, 2)) = False Then GoTo a
a:
i = i + 1
GoTo b

'check if two vertically adjacent cells have crossed over 4.1
b:
If Cells(i, 2) > 3.995 & Cells(i + 1, 2) < 4.01 Then

' interpolate the value if they have crossed 4.1
Range("S1")=WorksheetFunction.Forecast(4.1, Cells(i:i+1,2), Range("D" i ":D" i+1)
```

I am stuck at using forecast function as I currently don't know how I can tell excel to pick a block of cells inside a loop.

Comment: Do you want to detect both risings and fallings??

Comment: And so far you have tried?

Comment: why does it need to be VBA?  Wouldn't something like `=IF(AND(A2>=myValue,A1<=myValue),(A1+A2)/2,"")` work (you could add another clause inside `OR()` to handle crossing in either direction)?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I want to detect every time it will cross the value, weather its ascending or descending.

Comment: @brettdj i have included work I have done so far. I am stuck at using the forecast function.

Comment: @aucuparia I want to write a macro because i would like to run this script on hundreds of files.

Comment: Would an SQL statement on this data help? You can write SQL statements on Excel spreadsheets using ADODB.

Comment: Which column has your x-values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you would do the looping:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim sht As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, xvals, yvals, r As Long
    Dim th As Double, y1, y2, x1, x2


    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = sht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'assumes y vals in "B" and x vals in "N"
    'adjust as rtequired...
    yvals = sht.Range(sht.Cells(14, "B"), sht.Cells(lastRow, "B"))
    xvals = sht.Range(sht.Cells(14, "N"), sht.Cells(lastRow, "N"))

    th = 4.1

    For r = 1 To UBound(yvals) - 1
        y1 = yvals(r, 1)
        y2 = yvals(r + 1, 1)

        'pair of points crosses the threshold?
        If IsNumeric(y1) And IsNumeric(y2) Then
            If (y1 < th And y2 > th) Or (y1 > th And y2 < th) Then
                x1 = xvals(r, 1)
                x2 = xvals(r + 1, 1)
                '*************
                'calculate the intercept
                '*************
            End If
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Can i ask if there is a particular reason why you are using `yvals = sht.Range(sht.Cells(14, "B"), sht.Cells(lastRow, "B"))` instead of `yvals = sht.Range("B14:B" & lastrow )`? I would think that the latter is just tiny bit faster and makes for a more readable code

Comment: No particular reason - just personal preference.  I doubt it makes any difference performance-wise.

Comment: @tim williams I am trying to store all of the points it finds that fit the criteria in an array. At first, I am declaring the array as `ypoints() as Double` and `xpoints() as Double`. Then  I am trying to assign it values like so `ypoints(x,1) = y1` and `ypoints(x+1,1) = y2` and so on. However, I am getting "Subscript out of Range" error. What could be causing this? I know this has something to do with the dimensions of the array.

Comment: You are declaring a 1-D array and then addressing it as though it's a 2-D array...

Comment: Addressing the array as `ypoints(x)` and `ypoints(x+1)` still outputs the same error

Comment: @tim williams So i figured out that part of the problem. My intention originally was to declare a 1D dynamic array  because I don't know how many points the loop will find. It turns out that by declaring my array with a certain number of elements, I can store points in it and no longer recieve the subscript out of range error. However, the ReDim function no longer works because I have already declared the size of an array.

Comment: You would use `Redim Preserve` to resize your array without losing the existing contents.

Comment: If you want to get a collection of all of the pairs of points which cross the line then you would likely find it easier to declare a "Type" with parameters x1,y1,x2,y2 and create an array or Collection of those.  If you just add all the points individually to an array then you will have to sort them out later as pairs.

Comment: @TimWilliams Tim, I have been able to use your method and establish a script. Now, I am trying to implement something new. Instead of picking two vertically adjacent points, i want the code to skip the next point, and pick the point after. For example, if my array has data of `1 2 3 ` , the code currently looks to see if `1 ` or `2` has crossed 4.1. How can I make the code see if  `1` or `3` has crossed 4.1. I thought it might be as simple as modifying `y2 = yvals(r+2,1)`, but the code is giving me Subscript out of range Errors.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you forgot `&` in your forecast formula :

```
Range("S1")=Worksheetfunction.Forecast(4.1, , Range("D" & i ":D" & i+1)
```

Secondly, Forecast function requires three arguments - you only provide two of them. Please take a look [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/forecast.php) for more info on Forecast function.

Comment: I am struggling to input my arguments. How can i tell VBA to pick 2 cells as my X and 2 cells as my Y? I tried using the method you are seeing above, the "range("D"..." but VBA is giving me the "Expected line separator or .." error

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with this statement:

```
Range("S1")=WorksheetFunction.Forecast(4.1, Cells(i:i+1,2), Range("D" i ":D" i+1)
```

The main problem is you are calling the ranges wrong

```
Cells(i:i+1,2)
```

Should be:

```
Range(Cells(i,2),Cells(i+1,2))
```

or

```
Range("B" & i & ":B" & i + 1)
```

See above for why `Range("D" i ":D" i+1)` is also wrong.

You also are missing a ')' At the end of the statement.

So Adding it all together:

```
Range("S1")=WorksheetFunction.Forecast(4.1, Range("B" & i & ":B" & i + 1), Range("D" & i & ":D" & i+1))
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have fixed the issue with the forecast function. But now i just realized what my code does. The forecast function analyzes all of the points in the data column instead of looking at the points that are around 4.1. I suppose i need to tell excel to first store all of the points that lie around 4.1 and then run the forecast function on them. How can i go about doing this? Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @Bregs The best way would be to load all the Y values that are in your range of acceptable number, ie between 3.995 and 4.1, into an array.  And load all the corresponding x values into another array.  Then run the two arrays through the forecast equation.  Look into arrays and how to load them.  Try it on your own and comeback if you are having trouble and ask a new question.